# taking rest response value from javascript to apex class

Tags: apex, javascript, jquery

I'm getting Raw response for reports using rest API. Here is the code:

```
<apex:page controller="ApiReports_cls">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.ForceTK,'Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit-master/forcetk.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="https://www.google.com/jsapi" />

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
//Url Should be https://c.prerelna1.visual.pre.force.com/apex/AnalyticsDemo?reportId=00Ox0000000fX7XEAU

var reportId = '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.reportId}';
alert('Your report Id is ' +reportId);
if(reportId)
{
    var client = new forcetk.Client();

    client.setSessionToken('{!$Api.Session_ID}');

    var report = null;

    client.ajax("/v29.0/analytics/reports/"+reportId+"?includeDetails=true",function(response){

        report = response;
        $("#output").text(JSON.stringify(report, null, ' '));

    });
}
});
</script>

<div>
        <br/>
        <h1>Raw Response</h1>
<apex:outputText id="output1">
        <pre id="output"></pre>

</apex:outputText>

</div>

</apex:page>
```

I'm getting the Raw response in VF page. But, all i want is to display the Raw response in System.debug (to class).

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this, but here's a potential solution:

Because you're getting the raw response via javascript on the page, you'll need to add the reponse to the view state.  First you'll need some `<apex:form>` tags and then a hidden input field inside `<apex:inputHidden id="reportRawResponse" value="{!someControllerVariable}" />`

When you receive your response from the ajax request, find the `<input>` tag and set the value to your repsonse.

Finally, you'll need an `<apex:actionFunction>` to submit the form with your javascript after you set the value.

Once you submit the form, your controller should have access to the form raw response in the variable `someControllerVariable`.

Comment: Thank you Bradley. when i try to set the response value to <input:hidden> tag, the result is coming as null. See this:
<script>

client.ajax("/v29.0/analytics/reports/"+reportId+"?includeDetails=true",function(response){
        
        report = response;
        $("#output").text(JSON.stringify(report, null, ' '));
        var s = JSON.stringify(report, null, ' ');
        document.getElementById("{!$Component.hdnField}").value = s;
        
  });
</script>


<apex:form >
  <apex:inputHidden id="hdnField" value="{!theValue}" />
</apex:form>

when i load the form, theValue is null

Comment: The reason is because your `<script>` is not in between the `<apex:form>` tags.  Your `document.getElementById("{!$Component.hdnField}")` probably looks something like `document.getElementById("")` when rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sending the RAW response from VF to class, you can directly get the data in class by making a HTTP callout to the end point, something like this:

```
String url =  'reportingEndpointUrl';

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

req.setMethod('GET');
req.setEndpoint(url);
req.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());

Http http = new Http();

HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug('you willget the response here' + res.getBody());
```

But if you want to send it from VF then you could follow @Bradley' which uses `actionFunction` or you could use JS Remoting.

Comment: This is how I would do it. Not sure why he wanted the Ajax request.

Comment: Sorry, but i didn't get the 'reportingEndpointUrl'. Is it the Ajax request URL(Eg: /services/data/v29.0/analytics/reports/00Oi0000000xxpF/). Also, i want to acheive it through REST API not JSON.

Comment: Yes reportingEndpointUrl is the your rest endpoint URL for getting the reports. It will be complete URL and not like the partial URL that you have mentioned. The answer that I have given is based on REST API..